# Update a row of a class "son" and "father" does not receive update on UpdatedAt. It's possible to resolve?

Tags: parse-platform, nosql

I'm working with Parse.com on a personal project and I notice that all my classes that relate to others, when updated the "children", the other part of their relationship (the class "parent") does not get updated in the column "UpdatedAt ".

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: This may help you, if you haven't read it already. [Have you read this?](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-updating)